# Convert Rows to Columns using RxJS / TypeScript / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following table data:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 | 1 |
| 01/02/2000 | 2 |
| 01/01/2001 | 2 |
| 01/01/2002 | 1.5 |
| 01/02/2002 | 1.6 |

```
[{date: "01/01/2000", value: "1"},{date: "01/02/2000", value: "2"},{date: "01/01/2001", value: "2"},{date: "01/01/2002", value: "1.5"},{date: "01/02/2002", value: "1.6"}]
```

I would like to convert it to columns:

| Year | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 2 |
| 2001 |  | 2 |
| 2002 | 1.5 | 1.6 |

```
[{Year: "2000", Jan: "1", Feb: "2"},
{Year: "2001", Jan: "", Feb: "2"},
{Year: "2002", Jan: "1.5", Feb: "1.6"}]
```

How can I change it using RxJS / TypeScript / JavaScipt in Angular?

Thanks.

Comment: I think maybe you transposed Jan and Feb in your output for 2001 (jan = 2, feb = '')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below approach using reduce

```js
const initial = [{date: "01/01/2000", value: "1"},{date: "01/02/2000", value: "2"},{date: "01/01/2001", value: "2"},{date: "01/01/2002", value: "1.5"},{date: "01/02/2002", value: "1.6"}]

const allMonths = initial.reduce((prev, next) => {
  const date = next.date.substr(6,4) + '/' + next.date.substr(3,2)
  const month =  new Date(date).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
  return {...prev, [month]: ''}
}, {})

const temp = initial.reduce(
  (prev, next) => {
    const date = next.date.substr(6,4) + '/' + next.date.substr(3,2)
    const month =  new Date(date).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
    
    const Year = new Date(date).getFullYear()
    let prevYearVal = prev[Year]
    if(!prevYearVal) { prevYearVal = {Year,...allMonths} ;}
    return {...prev, [Year]: {...prevYearVal,Year, [month]: next.value}}
    
    return prev
  },
  {}
)
const final = Object.values(temp)
console.log(final)
```

Comment: Thanks @Owen, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @developer - is it? This is not cross browser. It does not work on Safari on MacOS or iOS. Thought you should know.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a number of steps to complete the transformation.

1. Convert string date into usable JavaScript date object

   - because the date is mm/dd/YYYY, rather then dd/mm/YYYY it must be transposed
   - then a new Date is constructed using the decomposed string
2. Then it is just a matter of constructing the new object
3. The output from that is each date with corresponding values that must be combined

   - The second iterator (`.reduce()`) combines the objects if the `Year` properly match

```js
const input = [{date: "01/01/2000", value: "1"},{date: "01/02/2000", value: "2"},{date: "01/01/2001", value: "2"},{date: "01/01/2002", value: "1.5"},{date: "01/02/2002", value: "1.6"}];

const result = input.map(i => {
  const [day, month, year] = i.date.split('/');
  const [_, monthName] = new Date(year, month - 1, day).toDateString().split(' ');
  return {
    Year: year,
    [monthName]: i.value
  }
}).reduce((acc, d, idx) => {
  if (idx == 0) { 
    acc.push(d);
  } else if (acc[acc.length - 1].Year == d.Year) {
    acc[acc.length - 1] = Object.assign(acc[acc.length-1], d);
  } else {
    acc.push(d);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The OP says it works well, and I like the implementation, but I notice a miss in that the expected second entry is `{Year: '2001', Jan: 2, Feb: ''}`.  Your version doesn't include the blank `Feb` node.

Comment: @ScottSauyet  I realized that from the beginning, but I am reluctant to "make up" data that is not in the source. It is just a bad practice. If the OP wants to take the risk that is the OP's prerogative. "_A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure._" -- Segal's Law about single source of truth.

Comment: Certainly there is a balancing act between that notion and the idea that we should return consistent data structures, not one with `year/jan/feb` and another with `year/jan`.  Obviously if this is to be displayed in a table, at some point that missing data has to be created, even if it's just a `... | ''` somewhere in the display code.  Whether this is the right place to do that is a good question.  But you knew it and made a reasonable choice, which is fine.  It just wasn't clear that you'd made an explicit decision.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that works similarly to answers from Owen and Randy, but it separates the month-name processing into its own helper function.  Written independently, the local variable names are all different, but they do the same work.  It is also structured as a single function call rather than a set of steps:

```js
const monthName = ((months) => (m) => months [m - 1])(
  '01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12' .split ('|') .map (
    m => new Date (`2021/${m}`).toLocaleString('default', {month: 'short'})
  )
)

const transform = (xs) => {
  const base = Object .fromEntries (
    [...new Set(input .map (
      ({date}) => date .slice (3, 5)
    ))]
    .map (month => [monthName (month), ""])
  )
  return Object .values (xs .reduce ((years, {date, value}) => {
    const Year = date .slice (6, 10), 
          Month = date.slice (3, 5)
    years [Year] = years [Year] || {Year, ...base}
    years [Year] [monthName(Month)] = value
    return years
  }, {}))
}

const input = [{date: "01/01/2000", value: "1"}, {date: "01/02/2000", value: "2"}, {date: "01/01/2001", value: "2"}, {date: "01/01/2002", value: "1.5"}, {date: "01/02/2002", value: "1.6"}]

console .log (transform (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

One advantage is that it doesn't call the `Date` constructor for every object, simply calling it once for every calendar month.  And if you don't want the locale string version but a fixed set of month names the helper can be even simpler:

```js
const monthName = ((months) => (m) => months [m - 1]) (
  'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec' .split ('|')
)
```

I tend to prefer functions written purely as expressions and not statement, so an alternate version might look like this:

```js
const transform = (
  xs, 
  base = Object .fromEntries (
    [...new Set (xs .map (
      ({date}) => date .slice (3, 5)
    ))]
    .map (month => [monthName (month), ""])
  )
) => Object .values (
  xs .reduce ((a, {date, value}, _, __, 
    Year = date .slice (6, 10), Month = date.slice (3, 5)
  ) => ({
    ...a, 
    [Year]: {Year, ...(a [Year] || base), [monthName (Month)]: value}
  }), {})
)
```

It works the same way, and is somewhat [less efficient](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern), but I find it cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Scott, it is indeed a lot cleaner implementation.